# Can I use Wi-Fi Direct and cellular data in an app?

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, connection, wifip2p

I have two+ Android devices. I would like the devices to send instructions to the other devices using Wi-Fi Direct, while at the same time being able to access the internet via their cellular data connection. It seems that using the Wi-Fi Direct interface is being treated as *the* primary connection, disabling the other connections, just like how Wi-Fi disables the cellular data connection.

How can I programmatically allow both to operate at the same time?

Currently the Wi-Fi Direct receiver is implemented according to Google's Android Developer documents. I was under the assumption that I could use Wi-Fi Direct much like I can use Bluetooth alongside other connections.

Comment: this is clearly a programming question.

Comment: It appears, this (if possible) would require root.  Is this feasible for you?

Comment: @Prmths turns out this isn't a problem on all devices, just some, my initial test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do that, you can check some articles over [here](https://sites.google.com/site/lotuseaterarpit/news/3g4gwififorandroidconcurrently) . One of the developers in XDA has developed an application to do that called [Super Download Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.opbyte.superdownload_lite)  and paid version of [Super Download - Fast!](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.opbyte.superdownload) . You can get details from [here](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/super-download-uses-mobile-data-wifi-for-faster-internet-speed/)  and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1667025) or you can do some [hacking](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/)  Here is the [source code](https://github.com/szym/barnacle)  of application which connect to 3G and WiFi to share the connection of the internet (But I am not sure how much it will help you). or try [decompiling](http://yeblon.com/how-to-decompile-android-apk-app-files) or [revers engineering](http://wanamlite.com/2013/02/21/apkmanager-v6-1-reverse-engineering-of-android-applications/) the [Super Download](http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/08db386a49c65023e567e7de6f9ca798/527f4081/2/2/0/8/3/2/3/SuperDownload_1.5.apk) app

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: @Duncan. There are *ten* links in the answer, including several to app download pages and a source code repository. It doesn't seem reasonable to expect the answerer to "summarize" the information in a collection of links of this nature.

Comment: @ekhumoro While this is an impressive and no doubt useful collection of links, there is almost no content in the question itself. At least some of the details should be included in the answer with the links provided for additional info and further research. If a few of these links break, the answer is useless.

Comment: I wrote what I thought useful which is even agreed by their person asking the question that is why I believe he might have accepted the answer and off all when I submitted the answer I had already decompiled the apps link that I gave and it’s not obfuscated that is why I mentioned it to decompiling it or reverse engineering it. Also the person did not mention any code so neither did I explain it. Thank you